# Saving new input strings to NSMutableArray iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am using below code to add strings to `NSMutableArray`. But the issue I am facing is that whenever I add a new value to the `NSMutableArray`, previous value gets deleted and new value comes in, so there is always a single value.

I have to save this `NSMutableArray` to `NSUserDefaults` so that I would use it on other screens too.

I have searched alot please do help me

code is:

```
- (IBAction)addChildren:(id)sender {
    inputChildName = nameOfChild.text;
    childArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self.childArray addObject:inputChildName];
    NSUserDefaults *childrenNamesForLabel = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [childrenNamesForLabel setObject:childArray forKey:@"children"];
    [childrenNamesForLabel synchronize];
    NSLog(@"CHILDREN ARRAY::: %@", childArray);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because whenever you receive your addChildren action you re-create the childArray which means it will contain 0 objects, then you add one object.

```
childArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self.childArray addObject:inputChildName];
```

Move `childArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` to an init or load method and it should work.

Comment: hey Markus, i did it and its working but now the issue is, whenever i come back on the this screen to add child it array gets initiated again as I have added the its initialization in viewdidload method. Now how can I get rid of it

Comment: Ok thanx I have resolve it by initializing the array with the saved array in nsuserdefaults in viewdidload method

Answer (score 1):

Every time you do this:

```
childArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

you create a new `NSMutableArray`. You have to put this line e.g. in `-viewDidLoad` to get this code working.

Answer (score 0):

inputChildArray and childarray are member variables of your class? then you should initialise the array in the init method or smth similar. so just move the line

```
// initialise array
childArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

into your init method.

Answer (score 0):

```
childArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

You are **initializing a new array object every time you save the new string** .. ..

this way you add one string to the array ..and save the new array in place of previous..

To solve this..add `childArray` as a `member variable` to your class.h file..

and in your `viewDidLoad` do this

```
childArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

then change your code to below

```
-(IBAction)addChildren:(id)sender{
inputChildName = nameOfChild.text;


[self.childArray addObject:inputChildName];

NSUserDefaults *childrenNamesForLabel = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[childrenNamesForLabel setObject:childArray forKey:@"children"];

[childrenNamesForLabel synchronize];

 NSLog(@"CHILDREN ARRAY::: %@", childArray);

}
```