# how to add objects to existing array in objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

I am new to objective c and having some problem with nsmutableArray.I have button and two textfields on my gui and i want that when i click on button the strings from textfields should be added to my existing array. But the problem is that when i click on button it always create new array.Help anybody.

my button code in myfile.m is as follows:

```
NSMutableArray* myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *strr=[textf stringValue];
NSString *strr1=[textf1 stringValue];
// [myArray addObject:strr]; // same with float values
// [myArray addObject:strr1];
[myArray addObject:strr];
[myArray addObject:strr1];
int i,j=0;
int count;
for (i = 0, count = [myArray count]; i < count; ){
    NSString *element = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"The element at index %d in the array is: %@", i, element); 
}
```

Comment: Please show the complete function code. Also please indent the code.

Comment: please next time use a sane code formatting.

Comment: and why you minus vote my question?? I have searched my question alot and have tried also some answers on stackoverflow but not solve my problem. i have searched and use this one also but :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654134/saving-new-input-strings-to-nsmutablearray-iphone

Comment: Your loop is an infinite loop: it will log the first element over and over forever. You need to increment `i` in the next (third) section of the `for` statement. (Better yet, use a `for…in` loop, which cannot have this problem. `for (NSString *element in myArray)`)

Comment: sorry some art of code is missing i have incremented t at the end of my button code. The problem is basically array:(

Answer (score 3):

Because you always create new array in this line:
`NSMutableArray* myArray = [NSMutableArray array];`

Make your array as property of your class object. Example:

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * array;
@end

@implementation MyClass

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if ( self ) {
        _array = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)onButtonClick {
    NSString *strr = [textf stringValue];
    NSString *strr1 = [textf1 stringValue];

    [self.array addObject:strr];
    [self.array addObject:strr1];

    for ( int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++ ) {
        NSString * element = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"The element at index %d in the array is: %@", i, element); 
    }
}

@end
```